# How to automatically deselect all items below the selected one flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, checkbox, deselect

I have a custom list view with selectable items. And I am trying to deselect all items automatically present below the one I selected. For Ex: Suppose there is 10 items in the list view and I deselected 5th then it should deselect all the items available below 5th. i.e(5,6,7,8,9)

Comment: can you include sample code

Comment: for (var item in _data)
              CheckboxListTile(
                value: item.isChecked,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    for (var i = 0; i <= _data.indexOf(item); i++) {
                      _data[i].isChecked = value!;
                    }
                  }
                  );
                },
                title: Text(item.text),
              ),

Comment: I mean the full sample widget

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this!

```dart
int selectedIndex = 0;  //default 0 means we should display all  checkbox selected

ListView.builder(
         itemCount: 10,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             return Checkbox(
              value: selectedIndex == 0
                              ? true //first loading all are checked
                   : index > selectedIndex  //selected index check
                   ? false //if 5 selected then 6,7,8,9,10 are blank
                   : true, //rest of them are checked

              onChanged:(val){
                 setState((){
                    selectedIndex = index;
                  });
               },
            );
           },
      ),
```